# How to merge unique values for a child array when merging objects

Tags: jq, yq

I want to merge the `.environments.default` and `.environments.dev` objects together, so that `dev` values override any `default` values and `default` values fill in anything not defined in the `dev` object. If I use `.environments.default * .environments.dev` most of the objects are merged correctly, except for the array lists under the `env` and `secrets` objects. The entire `dev` object is used, but I want the array lists to be merged with unique values.

Is there anyway to get this result with `jq`? If it helps I could also try doing this in `yq` with the YAML file.

I would also really like to know if this is possible without hardcoding `"env"` or `"secrets"` anywhere in the code.

When I use `.environments.default * .environments.dev` on the below source...

**Source:**

```json
{
"environments": {
    "default": {
      "config": {
        "security": {
          "user": 0,
          "group": 0
        },
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "memory": "256Mi",
            "cpu": "500m"
          }
        },
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "DEFAULT_ENV",
            "value": "DEFAULT_ENV_VALUE"
          },
          {
            "name": "BASE_URL",
            "value": "DEFAULT_BASE_URL"
          }
        ],
        "secrets": [
          {
            "secretID": "567",
            "mountPath": "/default/dir/to/567/path"
          },
          {
            "secretID": "123",
            "mountPath": "/default/dir/to/123/path"
          },
          {
            "secretUUID": "789",
            "mountPath": "/default/dir/to/789/path"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "dev": {
      "config": {
        "replicas": 1,
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "cpu": "5000m"
          }
        },
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "BASE_URL",
            "value": "DEV_BASE_URL"
          },
          {
            "name": "DEV_ENV_1",
            "value": "DEV_ENV_1"
          }
        ],
        "secrets": [
          {
            "secretID": "456",
            "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
          },
          {
            "secretID": "123",
            "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get...

**Current output:**

```json
{
  "config": {
    "security": {
      "user": 0,
      "group": 0
    },
    "resources": {
      "limits": {
        "memory": "256Mi",
        "cpu": "5000m"
      }
    },
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "BASE_URL",
        "value": "DEV_BASE_URL"
      },
      {
        "name": "DEV_ENV_1",
        "value": "DEV_ENV_1"
      }
    ],
    "secrets": [
      {
        "secretID": "456",
        "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
      },
      {
        "secretID": "123",
        "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
      }
    ],
    "replicas": 1
  }
}
```

but I want...

**Desired output:**

```json
{
  "config": {
    "security": {
      "user": 0,
      "group": 0
    },
    "resources": {
      "limits": {
        "memory": "256Mi",
        "cpu": "5000m"
      }
    },
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "BASE_URL",
        "value": "DEV_BASE_URL"
      },
      {
        "name": "DEV_ENV_1",
        "value": "DEV_ENV_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "DEFAULT_ENV",
        "value": "DEFAULT_ENV_VALUE"
      }
    ],
    "secrets": [
      {
        "secretID": "456",
        "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
      },
      {
        "secretID": "123",
        "mountPath": "/dev/dir/to/456/path"
      },
      {
        "secretID": "567",
        "mountPath": "/default/dir/to/567/path"
      },
      {
        "secretUUID": "789",
        "mountPath": "/default/dir/to/789/path"
      }
    ],
    "replicas": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your merging strategy. What determines that `.environments.default.config.env[0]` is kept in the output array `.config.env` (at pos 2), while `.environments.default.config.env[1]` is dropped. The only reason I can imagine is, that the latter's `.name` value already occurs in the target array's items. But as its `.value` value still differs, I cannot just check whole array items, yet I should keep it dynamic and not use field names. Then how? Same applies to `.environments.default.config.secrets[1]` where its `.secretID` already exists in the target, but `.mountPath` doesn't.

Comment: The env list should be unique by name and the secrets list should be unique by secretID. This is a deployment configuration so I want environment specific information. There will be a testing and prod environment too, that will need to be merged with the default configuration.

Comment: Understood, but you want a solution `without hardcoding "env" or "secrets" anywhere in the code.`, so how else can I address `.env.name` and `.secrets.secretID`? Do you expect me to use just `.name` and `.secretID`, and query for them on any array item I can find?

Comment: I was wondering if it could be unique by the first object key in the array? The env and secrets objects are optional. So I wanted to have a way to do the merge without a big if statement. And also future proof it a little for objects that don’t exist yet.

Comment: Object fields don't have an order conveyed by the format, only array items do. The order you observe in a specific file is just its current representation. Try changing the order of any fields within an object, then compare the altered version to the original. JSON processors (including jq and yq) are expected to yield that they are still equal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. name always comes before value and secretID always comes before mountPath when the file is created.

Comment: That's one of many valid representations of the logically same document. You can, of course, find out which one was read first (e.g. using `to_entries[0]`), which would work in your sense, but that wouldn't be a robust solution because the JSON format explicitly states that the same document can be represented with another field order, and you never know, which tools in the production chain may at some point decide to do so.

Comment: (Take for example [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), a jq rewrite in Go. It always returns objects with their fields sorted in alphabetical order, and it is allowed to do so based on this rule. Thus, in your case, `.mountPath` would come before `secretID`, while `.name` and `.value` would still be in the "original" order.)

Comment: OK, jq doesn't seem to do that, but I understand your point, that it is not an ideal approach. Just for the fun of it, how would you do it anyway? Or how would you do it by hardcoding the name and secretID values?

Answer (score 1):

From the [comments thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998185/how-to-merge-unique-values-for-a-child-array-when-merging-objects?noredirect=1#comment137507455_77998185):

> The env list should be unique by name and the secrets list should be unique by secretID. […] I was wondering if it could be unique by the first object key in the array? […] name always comes before value and secretID always comes before mountPath

> Object fields don't have an order conveyed by the format, only array items do. The order you observe in a specific file is just its current representation.

> Just for the fun of it, how would you do it anyway?

So, let the fun begin:

This captures and iterates over all items of non-empty arrays from the `.default` branch (saving the array path with `paths(arrays | select(has(0)))`, each item's value with `getpath(…)[]`, and the first item's key and value using `to_entries[0]`). The iteration's base document is the merge you already performed, but with these arrays removed from the `.default` branch, so the saved items can be individually tested and appended to it if they pass the condition that no other first key's value matches theirs: `IN(.[][$v0.key]; $v0.value) | not`.

```bash
.environments | [.default | paths(arrays | select(has(0))) as $p
  | getpath($p)[] as $v | {$p,$v,v0:($v | to_entries[0])}
] as $a | reduce $a[] as {$p,$v,$v0} ((.default | delpaths([$a[].p])) * .dev;
  setpath($p; getpath($p) | . + [select(IN(.[][$v0.key]; $v0.value) | not) | $v])
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-435Dd59AzD)

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for posting this. I can't wait to play around with it in jqplay and learn some new functionality of jq.

Comment: Hi @pmf, This works great, thank you very much! It took me a few hours, but I think I understand most of the logic. I could have never figured this out on my own, thanks again.

Comment: I added a little more logic to the "test and append" section for cases where the array exist in the `default` branch, but not the `dev` branch. Let me know what you think. `.environments | 
[.default | paths(arrays | select(has(0))) as $p
  | getpath($p)[] as $v | {$p,$v,v0:($v | to_entries[0])}
] as $a | 
reduce $a[] as {$p,$v,$v0} ((.default | delpaths([$a[].p])) * .dev;
  if getpath($p) == null then
      setpath($p; getpath($p) | . + [$v])
  else
      setpath($p; getpath($p) | . + [select(IN(.[][$v0.key]; $v0.value) | not) | $v])
  end
)`

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, I don't see any difference in the final output whether the arrays are removed from the `.default` branch or not. Is that done just because there is no reason for those arrays to even be considered as part of the initial merge or can you think of a situation where leaving the arrays in the `default` branch might produce the wrong result?